# Where can I found a precompiled libtdjson.so?

Tags: tdlib

I want to use TDLib JSON interface from PHP FFI, but i requires `libtdjson.so` to run.

As I understand, [it is not an option](https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/2188) to compile TDLib on a 1 GB server.

Where can I download a precompiled `libtdjson.so`?

Comment: https://github.com/ForNeVeR/tdlib.native/releases